# Database design concepts: is it necessary to have a primary key when I use two or more foreign key?

Tags: database-design

I am not sure if I am doing things right here:

1) is ok to put in one table all the user information (name, last name, mail, password, city and state)?

2) is ok how cities are related to states?

3) The user is able to create a challenge for one subject, level, in one state, one city and one date. (single_challenge table). One or more users can register to this challenge (registration_sc). Is it necessary to have a primary key on "single_challenge" table, when I use two or more foreign key? Is this design well-posed?

4) If I want to allow user to create a tournament challege, (same as single_challenge table) but with two more options: "maximum inscriptions" and "end date". I should create another table called "tournament_challenge" or I can add these two  fields to "single_challenge" table?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think design decicions are half engineer-matter and half artist-matter. There are things that can be tagged as bad practice, but many other depends on many factors and are linked to the "application domain" reality. For me, your question falls into this category:

1) There is one bad thing: You should keep only the city ID, not the state ID, because State ID is derived from City ID (it can be retrieved from City ID) 
The rest seems to be fine if you have decided that it is not possible for a user to have several addresses.

2) I think it is OK. One city belongs to a State, a State holds several cities (One-to-many relation)

3) Here again, you should remove the State ID, because City ID is enough. The id_user is fine, but you could also remove it and qualify the relation (registrations_sc) with an attribute that pointed to the order of registration. Then the first registered user for the challenge would be its creator.

About the primary key: Whether you have several foreign keys or not is not relevant. What you need yo know is if the combination of certain fields determine uniquely the whole row. That is a candidate key. If a user can only place a challenge in a city at given level for one subject in a single date, then {user_id, city_id, level_id, subject_id, date} is a candidate key and you don't NEED another primary key. Anyway, you could (and probably should) still decide to have your own autonumeric, single-field primary key for performance and simplicity reasons. In that case, you should not forget to define an unique-index on the combination of fields of the candidate key, so you cannot insert duplicates.

4)Again, it is up to you to take one path or the other. There are several ways to implement it. You can add those fields to the table and leave them null for single challenges. You can use different tables. You can also use the single_challenge table for both, and create another table to keep "maximum inscriptions" and "end date", along with the foreign key of "single_challenge". This table would be only populated for challenges that are tournaments. You must know how are you going to exploit your model, and design an implementation that:
1) Is technically correct (but many can be)
2) AND is also practical and make your life easy (simplifying your querys, insertions, deletions, etc.)

I hope it can help.

Comment: Thanks! When you said, "you should not forget to define an unique-index on the combination of fields of the candidate key, so you cannot insert duplicates", isn't this been covered with the pk id_single_challenge?

Comment: NO! The id_single_challenge is only a number... You could insert two different challenges (different in id_single_challenge) with the same combination of {user_id, city_id, level_id, subject_id, date} and the DB would not complain if you didn't define the unique index for those columns.

Comment: Good point! Please, help me closing this concept: The user may have two challenges the same date (and same city_id, level_id, subject_id) but not at the same time. In this case I should add to the table the additional field "time" with the unique-index property?

Comment: You must include the time column into the unique index. An unique index should contain the minimal combination of columns whose combined values can not be duplicated. If you mark the time column as unique, you cannot have two challenges at the same hour, no matter the day, user, etc. You must define an unique compound index that contains all the columns whose combination cannot repeat.

Answer (score 0):

1)Yes, that is fine to put all that info in the user table.

2)Yes, the one-to-many relationship is the right way to do it.

3)You always need a primary key. You can have a composite key using two foreign keys, if that is what you want, but that is usually for intermediary tables. In composite keys using MySQL Workbench, foreign keys must also be marked as primary keys. Select both foreign keys using "Ctrl" key, and then set to primary key.

4)Either is possible, but from it would be better to create a separate table for the tournaments.